# Import from /client folder in jsx files

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I try to import a helper from /client folder on my meteor application in jsx file. (The server hat its own helper in the /server directory)

Somehow while loading meteor say that the module is not found in the jsx file.

So my question is - does the server load all the jsx files before the client uses them? If this is the case I will be not capable to use the /client folder and should use something like /frontend.

Any other suggestions?

My structure looks like this

- imports/api/users/services/userServices.js (basic)
- imports/api/users/services/server/userServices.js (extends the basic)
- imports/api/users/services/client/userServices.js (extends the basic)
- imports/ui/components/SomeComponent.jsx (imports ...client/userServices.js)

Comment: The server loads all files in the way you import them from the `server/main.js` file. It may be helpful to add the code of the files so we can try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: The code is huge because it is a whole project, but I described on top the structure of my files, maybe the server needs to load first some client files somehow and doesnt find them?

Comment: I think this is not related to the structure but some faulty code line. Module not found is usually thrown in Meteor client, when the module is not found **at runtime** or when a dynamically imported module has syntax errors. However, it appears in both cases at runtime, because if the Error would be thrown at startup it would show the "errors prevent startup" message on the screen insead of a page. Edit: please specify where the error is thrown and add the error stack as well, since the imports structure alone is not helpful enough to determine the error.

Comment: @Jankapunkt Yes that was the problem, thank you! Now it is solved.